# A simple statistics question on percentile ranks

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say that A scored in the 70th percentile on the SAT.  B scored in the 35th percentile.

Did B score 50% lower than A (35/70=0.5)?  Or did B score 35% lower (70%-35%=35%).

I'm getting a little tripped up here because I'm dealing with percentile ranks rather than raw scores.  Thanks.

Comment: $A$ was ranked $35$ percentile points higher in the distribution than $B$ was.  $B$ was ranked $35$ percentile points lower in the distribution than $A$ was. Most other statements about their relative positions could be be confusing and should be avoided.

Comment: I think a good convention is that if you were to say 35% lower, to say "35 percentage points lower".

Comment: You can say:"The porportion of the students, who have more points  than B and less than A, on the SAT, is 35%". Your first statement is definitely wrong, because you do not know the distribution of the sat-scores.